# Error for jQuery ajax() if it gets data back ONLY in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, timeout

I have met some problem with jQuery ajax() in Safari, so I created some simple code to test.

A request is sent to PHP file and after 10 seconds, in all other browsers, it get "returned data" and alert "succeeded" then "completed"; but in Safari, it alert "error" and "completed", and can get no data.

If just change the 10 seconds to 9 (sleep(9);), it will also work in Safari. So why is 10 seconds a critical point for Safari? How to make Safari functions well like other browsers for ajax()?

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            timeout: 10000,
            url: "processor.php",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
              $("#status").html(data);
              alert('succeeded');
            },

            error: function (request, status, error) {
              alert('error');
            },

            complete: function () {
              alert('completed')
            }
          });

          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="send request" />
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    sleep(10);
    echo json_encode("Returned Data");
?>
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated,
Sean Liu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting `async: true` in the ajax properties. 10 seconds could be considered as a timeout.

Comment: wow, thank you very much, that works! I have not fully understood the meaning of async property. Thanks again for your help, have a good day!

Comment: yw.. async (asynchronous) means that the browser will attempt the connection in the background and will not halt the main activity while for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank that is a bug  in safari i think because the same code works fine in rest of the browsers only breaks in safari if async:false is there